# how to find relation R^2

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Suppose S is a set of airports, and R is the following relation on S: aRb if and only if
there is a direct flight from a to b. Explain your answers to the following questions and
use common sense.

a. Is R reflexive?
b. Is R symmetric?
c. Is R transitive?
d. What is the meaning of the relation R^2? Specifically, when are two airports R^2 related?

My attempt : R is not reflexive as a flight don't fly from same station to the same city.
R may or may not be symmetric as a flight may be direct from a to b and not necassary from b to a. R is not transitive also.

Can any one help me with the forth part i dont know what is R^2.

Answer (score 3):

So far so good. Regarding the last question, the composition of relations works as follows: if $R$ and $Q$ are two relations over the same set, then $x(Q\circ R)z$ iff there exists $y$ such that $xRy$ and $yQz$, that is in loose terms, you can go from $x$ to $z$ via $Q\circ R$ iff you can go from $x$ to some $y$ (via $R$) from which you can go to $z$ (via $Q$). In your example, $xR^2z$ iff there exists an airport $y$ *to* which you can fly directly from $x$, and *from* which you can fly directly to $z$.

Comment: I've never seen $R^2$ before. Just to clarify, in general if $R$ is reflexive, $R^2 = R$, yes?

Comment: @SimonS: not really, $R$ is reflexive iff it contains the diagonal, which is not really relevant. In fact, $R^2\subseteq R$ is equivalent to transitivity. If $R$ is reflexive, then $R^2 = R$ is equivalent to transitivity.

Comment: In this example suppose airports were reflexive with themselves (e.g., there was a tourist sightseeing trip), then $aR^2b$ if $aRb$ as $aRa$ for all $a$, hence here at least $R^2 = R$. I'm sure I'll kick myself for not seeing one, but could you give an example where $R^2$ is a strict subset of $R$ and $R$ is transitive?

Comment: @SimonS: say $S = \{a,b\}$ and $R = \{(a,b)\}$. Then, from $a$ we can only go to $b$ but from $b$ we can't go anywhere, so $R^2 = \emptyset$

Comment: Ok, a "corner case"; thanks.

Comment: @SimonS: since that's math, it quite  a lot about "corner cases"

Comment: Ha, I know! Just haven't thought about equivalence relations for a while.