# Relation p^3 on set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

For the relation p = `{(1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 3), (4, 2)}` on the set `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, determine the relation p^3.

I get that p^3 is p°p°p but how do I apply this to the exercise? Could p be described as = `{(a, d), (b, c), (b, c), (d, b)}`, and the set as `{a, b, c, d}` and then I just have to apply this three times?

Comment: This should be of help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048324/how-to-find-relation-r2

Answer (score 1):

Given a relation $R$ over some set $A$, we define the composition of $R$ with itself as $$R\circ R := \{(a,c)\in A\times A\phantom{i} | \phantom{i} \exists b : aRb \phantom{i} \& \phantom{i}bRc\}.$$ Given your set $p$, we could quite easily manually check which elements satisfy this definition. As a matter of fact, this turns out to be the set $$p^3 := p\circ p\circ p = \{(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (4,4)\}.$$

Comment: The theory looks all fancy and such, but how do you actually *apply* this in detail?

Comment: @DavidAffolter it stops looking fancy once you actually understand the definition. For $p^2$, you're looking for pairs of the form $(a,b),(b,c)$ in $p$, and if you find one, it means that $(a,c)$ is in $p^2$. For $p^3$ we just extend this to a three-pair 'chain' $(a,b),(b,c),(c,d)$. If such a 'chain' exists in $p$, then $(a,d)\in p^3$ (in your case, one example is $(1,4)\to (4,2) \to (2,3)$, which implies $(1,3)\in p^3$).